# Grails remoteField - Can I call a render/redirect?

Tags: ajax, grails

I'm not looking for a div update. I'm looking for a full page "refresh"

So I have a tag:

```
<g:remoteField controller="person" action="updatePerson" id="${personInstance.id}" paramName="search" name="updatePerson" value="${personInstance?.favoriteBreed}" />
```

In my attached method, I want to perform the action of updating the domain object, then refresh the entire page. I've tried both renders and redirects to simple actions within the application, but nothing is called. So I'm thinking this isn't possible with the remoteField tag.

Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why reimplementing via AJAX the normal behaviour of a page? Why don't you just call a redirect to the right action at the end of the called controller?

Let's say you are in the view resulted from the showPerson action. In this view, call the updatePerson with a simple (don't care about the params attribute, it's only an example):

```
<g:Link controller="person" action="updatePerson" id="${personInstance.id}" params="${name: 'search'}">click me</g:link>
```

and in the controller do something like:

```
def updatePerson = {
  // your own updating stuff

  redirect(action: "show", id: person.id)
}
```

Isn't it easier? :)

Comment: Well yes, technically. But I need a text field that makes an AJAX call to the database to update immediately. So normal text fields are (I think?) out of the question.

Comment: I understand, but you are talking about a full page refresh. So, AJAX become not useful, doesn't it?

Comment: I suppose - it's an odd situation. You are 100% right though.

Answer (score 0):

`<g:remoteField />` have the event `onSuccess` that can be used to do what you want. You can check more options [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteField.html).

Try (not tested):

```
<g:remoteField controller="person" action="updatePerson" 
    id="${personInstance.id}" paramName="search" name="updatePerson"    
    value="${personInstance?.favoriteBreed}" onSuccess="reloadPage()" />
```

And you will need to create the javascript function:

```
function reloadPage() {
  window.location.reload();
}
```